# Smart Pointer Variable to Function

Tags: c++

I'm studying C++ smart pointer, and I have a question.

```cpp
void showMap(???, const int row, const int col) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            std::cout << (map[i][j] == 0 ? "○" : "●") << '\t';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void saveMap(???, const int row, const int col) {
    std::ofstream fout("mapdata.txt");
    if (!fout.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open the file!";
        exit(0);
    }

    fout << row << " " << col << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            fout << map[i][j] << " ";

        fout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);

    int row, col;

    std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<int[]>[]> map = loadMap(row, col);

    if (map != nullptr)
    {
        showMap(map, row, col);
        map[0][1] = 0;
        showMap(map, row, col);
        saveMap(map, row, col);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to pass smart pointer var to function, and I don't know how to do it.

What parameter should I use for `???` at the functions?

Of course there is an simple way, `std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<int[]>[]> (&map)` but I don't want to do like this.

Is there any other way to pass smart pointer var to function?

Thanks.

Comment: Smart pointers are better to use than raw non-owning pointers (in many cases), but even if there are specializations of `std::unique_ptr` for arrays, please try to prefer `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Why don't you want to do it that way? You could add a typedef to make it easier to write

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm studying smart pointer so that I'm trying to use only smart pointers :) Thanks anyway!

Comment: @AlanBirtles I just wondered is there any other way.

Comment: @EugeneFitzher So your question is basically. "I know I should do it this way, but I just want to ask if there is another worse way I can do the same thing?" ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function signature beside the part that it allows to pass data to the function, is also an essential part of the documentation. So the chosen description of the parameters should explain what the function can do or won't do with the arguments.

In the case of `showMap` and `saveMap` these functions do neither claiming ownership on the smart pointer nor do they change the object the smart pointer is pointing to. And this is something that should be expressed by the function signature.

So as `saveMap` and `showMap` do not claim ownership you can either pass the raw-pointer the `std::unique_ptr` points to your functions e.g. `saveMap(map.get(), row, col);` or you can even use const reference, to show that you won't modify the object.

With `using` you can make your code a bit more readable for such situations:

```
using map_t = std::unique_ptr<int[]>[];

//...
std::unique_ptr<map_t> map;
//...

void saveMap(const map_t &map, const int row, const int col) {
}

void saveMap(const map_t &map, const int row, const int col) {
}
```

You should not pass the `unique_ptr` (or a `shared_ptr`) as a reference if the function you pass the smart pointer to does not do anything with the ownership, and you would limit your function to only accept `unique_ptr` as arguments, which a huge restriction if the function does not need to deal with the ownership.

Comment: Thanks!
`You should not pass the unique_ptr as a reference, if you don't plan to change that unique_ptr`, then will it be okay if I use `shared_ptr` ?

Comment: @EugeneFitzher the same is true with `shared_ptr` if the function does not claim the ownership, plans to change the object in the smart pointer, or passes the ownership to another place it should not get the object as a smart pointer, instead, [`observer_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr) should be used, but as it is experimental right now, you will for now use the raw pointer that you get by calling `get()` on the smart pointer.

Comment: Uhm... I don't understand that what is different between `using map_t = std::unique_ptr<int[]>[]; void ~~(map_t * map ,...)` and `void ~~(std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<int[]>[]> &map, ...)` ?

Comment: @Eugene Fitzher `std::unique_ptr<int[]>[]` represents the type managed by `std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<int[]>[]>`,  so as you want to pass a pointer to the type you manage by `std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<int[]>[]>` it has to be a pointer to `std::unique_ptr<int[]>[]` which would be `std::unique_ptr<int[]>[] *`. Using a `using map_t = std::unique_ptr<int[]>[];`  maks that just easier to read. It is about that you don't want to pass the smarpointer `map` as reference to the function but the object it is pointing to, which is an array of  `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @EugeneFitzher If you have `std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<int[]>[]> &map` in the signature, then the function says it potentially changes to what object the `unique_ptr` the `map` parameter represents will point to. If your function does not do that it should be either a const reference of a non-owning pointer. And a const ref to a `unique_ptr` normally not what you want to do.

Comment: This doesn't seem right at all. Passing a `const &` surely conveys intent much better then passing a raw pointer.

Comment: @super In case `const std::unique_ptr<some_t>& obj` would for sure prevent the `unique_ptr` referenced by `obj` to be changed, but e.g. in case of  `const std::shared_ptr<some_t>& obj` that would not prevent the claiming of ownership. But why would you want to limit your function to accept `const std::unique_ptr<some_t>& obj`  if you can create a general-purpose function that accepts `some_t *obj`, then this function can be used no matter if the object is managed by a smart pointer or if it has automatic storage duration.

Comment: @super and that's not only my opinion but is mentioned multiple times by cppcon talkers and c++ committed members.

Comment: @t.niese If you don't want to limit your function, you can take a `const T&`, why involve pointers at all? Also, the point of using a `shared_ptr` is that it can be shared. So passing it around and trying to prevent people from keeping their own copy makes little sense in that scenario. Then one would pass, again, a reference to the pointed object, not the shared pointer itself.

Comment: @super `const some_t&` would prevent the object passed from being modified, that is indeed a good idea for `showMap` but for a case like `saveMap` it might not be an option. You indeed then could use `saveMap( some_t &)`, but as always if non-const reference parameters, you won't see at the calling side that the passed argument could be changed and should - well that is needed opinion based - avoided. A raw pointer has the problem that it can be `nullptr` which might not meet the requirements but there the cppcoreguidlines suggest the usage of `not_null`.

Comment: @super the point of `shared_ptr` is to have shared ownership, but a function that only accesses the object for the time it was called, and does not store it anywhere do not claim ownership, so using a `shared_ptr` just to be able to pass it to the function, is not the right approach.

Comment: @t.niese I would say saving something to a file does not normally involve modifying the object. And obviously you shouldn't use a `shared_ptr` just to be able to pass a temporary copy to a function. What that has to do with what I wrote, or how that backs up your reasoning I have no idea. There is still not a single good point explaining why we would want to pass a pointer in this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

A `std::unique_ptr` cannot be shared - it wouldn't be particularly unique if you could!

Two solutions:

1. Use `std::shared_ptr` in place of `std::unique_ptr`.
2. Pass by reference: i.e. `???` becomes `std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<int[]>[]>&`.

Comment: Thanks!

But is there any other way for insteading `std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<int[]>[]> &` ?

Comment: There isn't any reason to pass a smart pointer to OP's function; it can "ride" on its caller's ownership status.